# Op amp circuit design

Tags: operational-amplifier, design, impedance

I am having trouble with understanding how to design circuits involving op amps.

I need to design a circuit using as less op amps as possible which has the following characteristics:

- high input impedance (greater than 100k)
- low output impedance (smaller than 100)
- can be adjusted with a single 47k potentiometer over the range 0 to -10
- gain should vary linearly with potentiometer rotation

I really don't understand how to complete this...

Comment: We don't just do your homework for you here.  Show that you've done some work, and explain exactly what you are stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

If we can design a bit of a "silly" circuit, then the following would kinda work. (for one opamp)  (Gain is not quite linear.)  You've got to pick R4 to give a gain a bit more than 20... but I'm too lazy to work out the exact number.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFnngZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you feed your signal into the pot you get a linear output level from 0 to 1 coming out - that sounds like a start. If you then buffer the signal before the pot you get >100k input impedance and, if you make that op-amp an inverting amplifier with Rin = 110k and Rf at 1.1Mohm you get inverting gain of 10. All that remains is to add a buffer op-amp (unity gain non-inverting) to the pot output and this should work. I'm struggling to see how you would achieve it without two op-amps unless the signal levels were small and you could use a 200 ohm potentiometer feeding the output directly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMWFAB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It's better to replace R2 by the pot R1 (47 k) connected as a rheostat; then R3 should be 4,7 k... but, unfortunately, the input resistance will decrease:( and a follower will be necessary.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist - or use a 2Mohm pot

Comment: Another suggestion - connect the right end of R2 to the slider of the potentiometer R1, and use the op-amp output as a circuit output (i.e., implement the negative feedback network as a T-bridge). Thus R3 can be high enough while R2 and R1 - low enough.